# Max and substring function SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, max

I need some help in returning the max value for each OrderID.

Example I have a table that have OrderID and there are like: A04-01, B17-10, C12-01, etc.... I'm trying to do a Select where it shows me the max number for each letter. Example: A04-01 is the lowest, and A17-01 is the highest for the letter A. All this was built in Oracle Procedure but we getting rid of Oracle, so I need to re-create it in Microsoft SQL Server. Thank You.

Comment: A17-01 must be considered 1701 or 17?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table  (OrderID varchar(25))
Insert into @YourTable values
 ('A04-01')
,('A17-10')
,('B17-10')
,('C12-01')

Select Letter = left(OrderID,1)
      ,MinVal = min(OrderID)
      ,MaxVal = max(OrderID)
 From  @YourTableYourTable    
 Group By left(OrderID,1)
```

Returns

```
Letter  MinVal  MaxVal
A       A04-01  A17-10
B       B17-10  B17-10
C       C12-01  C12-01
```

Comment: I ran it, excellent, how do I replace ` ('A04-01')
,('A17-10')
,('B17-10')
,('C12-01') `
for the values in my `ordered` column from my table `insorders`?

Comment: @JoelJacobson The table variable is demonstrative.  Remove everything above SELECT and replace (at)YourTable with your actual table name

Comment: @JoelJacobson Happy it helped

Answer (score 0):

If the `OrderID` is what exactly you mentioned, try this:

```
WITH ABC
AS
(
Select OrderID, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition by OrderID Order by OrderID desc) as Row_Indicator
From table
)
Select * From ABC
Where ABC.Row_Indicator = 1
```